# Java - Android SDK 8 - XML Parsing with DocumentBuilderFactory terminating strings after entities

Tags: java, android, xml

I am writing an application in Java for Android (SDK v8) that parses XML and puts the entries into a ListView. This part works fine. I am parsing the XML with a DocumentBuilder, which is terminating the strings it's outputting after an entity - excluding the entity itself. The entities I am using are standard entites &(quot, amp, apos, lt, gt); I have also tried using numeric entities in my source XML (e.g. &# 38; without the space, just so you can see what I'm outputting) and this leads to a crash of my app, with logcat reporting "unterminated entity ref".

To test that I am not using invalid XML, I have tried viewing the XML with Google Chrome - which displays it perfectly. The entry `blah &amp; blah.txt` is truncated to `blah`. The XML I am parsing is below:

EDIT: Much shorter XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>  
<root>  
<object>  
<id>ROOT</id>  
<type>directory</type>  
<name>../</name>  
</object>  
<object>  
<id>09F010C143B84573A36C50F3EF7E0708</id>  
<type>file</type>  
<name>blah &amp; blah.txt</name>  
</object>   
<object>  
<id>85CF028B838D4E0096C081B987C97045</id>  
<type>file</type>  
<name>Epilist.m3u</name>  
</object>  
</root>
```

EDIT: XML parsing class
EDIT2: Below is a complete class that (with the help of others) should now be bug free. Anyone is welcome to use this class - I am providing it as Public Domain code. You do not need to reference that I originally produced this code to use it. It is designed for Android, but by replacing references to 'Log.e' it can easily be used on any Java platform as far as I know.

```
package tk.dtechsoftware.mpclient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            // HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        // return DOM
        return doc;
    }

    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return n.item(0).getTextContent(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: We really don't need 100 lines of the same type of node. Please consider shortening your code down to a small sample that conveys what you are trying to do. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: More importantly, post your parsing code.

Comment: Sorry guys, just realized I've provided far too much XML data there. The important element is near the bottom, and has the `<name>` of `blah &amp; blah.txt`

Comment: I have edited my post so that it contains much less XML data, and now also contains my XMLParser class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its guaranteed that an element node has only one child node containing its text content. The contents can as well be split across multiple child nodes.

Your `getElementValue` method can probably be replace by a simple call to [`elem.getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29).

Comment: I cast the node in the getValue() function as an element and used the .getTextContent() method as you suggested and this worked perfectly. Thankyou very much!

Comment: @NFSGamer: A typecast shouldn't be needed as the method is defined on the `Node` interface.

Comment: Of course, I was looking for this method on the NodeList object. Silly me. This has made my code look more elegant, thankyou!